# Taking the address of a direct non-static member of an object without being constructed results in UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this example

```cpp
struct X { int i; };
extern X xobj;
int* p3 = &xobj.i;  // #1
X xobj;  // #2
```

The declaration at `#2` causes the construction of `xobj`, the taking address operation of the member subobject `i` is before that point. According to [class.cdtor] p3

> To form a pointer to (or access the value of) **a direct non-static member** of an object obj, **the construction of obj shall have started and its destruction shall not have completed**, otherwise the computation of the pointer value (or accessing the member value) **results in undefined behavior**.

So, the operation at `#1` is UB?

Comment: Don't you assume with extern X xobj that the object is already constructed?

Comment: @Sebastian No, there is only one translation unit. The unique definition of `xobj` is at `#2`.

Comment: _So, the operation at `#1` is UB?_ Yes.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks for confirming that. So, the comment about `xobj` in this formal [example](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#example-1) is wrong.

Comment: Normative text is just wrong

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks. I have posted this issue.

Comment: Actually, I think I confused the example with something else. I'm not sure how to apply [class.cdtor]/3 to the example.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think the second sentence of [class.cdtor]p3 should be moved in another sole paragraph. It sounds that the second sentence is irrelevant to the subject of [class.cdtor]p3.

Comment: What does "direct non-static" mean?

Comment: @palapapa See https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#1 and https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#4